# Why was this question migrated to ELU?

Tags: discussion, migration

Why was [Difference between “did + verb” and just “verb+ed”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118683/) migrated to ELU?

It was apparently asked by a nonnative speaker unable to distinguish, say, *I did answer* from *I answered*.

Since all native speakers know how to use the two forms appropriately, I don't see why such a trivial question should be considered *On Topic* for ELU anyway, but that's not the point.

I definitely don't see how the question could be ***Off*** Topic for ELL, so why has it been moved from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was first asked on ELU, and received answers. It was then asked again on ELL, and received more answers. While we allow questions which are *closed* on ELU to be posted to ELL, cross-site posting of duplicate questions is not encouraged. As the question is on-topic on both sites and was posted to ELU first, I migrated it back over to ELU so that the mods there could merge the answers from both copies of the question into one.

I found an [old answer of mine](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/639/289) on the subject of cross posting, copied here for reference:

> This question has been [asked on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71938/can-i-cross-post-my-question-from-one-site-to-another/71949#71949), and Jeff Atwood gave a rather definitive response:
>
> > Cross-posting questions is strongly discouraged. See
> >
> > [Is it possible to post questions across a couple of the sites because it's debatable which site it fits best?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64073#64073)
> >
> > > Allowing cross-posting is a slippery slope.
> > >
> > > If you might have slightly better odds of getting an answer by posting it on two sites, well, by gum, why not maximize your odds by posting it on twenty sites!
> > >
> > > There are some questions which fall into grey areas between sites, and I think it's OK to ask and delete, then re-ask if you feel you have asked on the wrong site.
> > >
> > > But as a general rule, do not cross-post questions, please. Pick a site and go with it.
> >
> > It is also ok to ask two different versions of a question but you MUST tailor it to the audience on that site. Copying and pasting would put you on the road to account suspension.
>
> So, it seems the answer is clear; if you cross-post a question it must be tailored to the site, the idea behind which seems to be that you're *expecting a different answer from the users on each site*.  That doesn't, in general, seem to be the case in the questions we've seen cross-posted between ELL and ELU; the goal simply seems to be to reach a wider audience in hopes of achieving a single answer. So these question should certainly be closed.
>
> The concept behind not cross-posting is the same concept behind not asking duplicate questions; you don't want to separate the content up between multiple places. You want all the answers to be found in one place. If a question is on-topic on multiple sites (which can happen) you simply choose what you think is the best site and ask it there. Cross-posting shouldn't usually be necessary.

Whew! That's a lot of indenting ;)

So we wanted to keep the great answers this question had on ELL and ELU all in the same place, and since it was on topic on both sites it defaulted to the first site it was asked on. I hope that addresses all the concerns you have on this topic; please let me know if not and I'll try to answer them.

P.S. As far as whether or not this question is on-topic for ELU, that's something the community there will have to decide. I suppose in theory it's possible that the question could be migrated back here; I certainly wouldn't have a problem with that. But when I pinged simchona about the matter she seemed perfectly happy with the merge, so as far as I'm aware the question is happily on ELU at the moment. If that changes I'll be happy to welcome it back; just with all the answers in one place! :)

And if it helps, [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118871/difference-between-did-verb-and-just-verb-ed) is actually the copy of the question that used to be on ELL; you can see the migration-lock-merge notices on the post. The one you linked in the question is the original post the questioner made on ELU, which the ELL-migrated answers were merged into.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't actually realised that *the same OP* had posted the same question on ELU first. I still think such basic questions are simply too trivial for ELU. But every time I suggest anything like that over there I seem to get overruled by the majority, so I guess I'll just keep my head down for now. If we ever get an option on ELU to closevote as Off Topic in favour of ELL (*and* if I notice the question again), I'll do that. For now though, I'm satisfied with this answer here.