# Should we close a question that is a duplicate on ELU?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, english-language-and-usage

In [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/309862/is-i-digress-an-idiomatic-expression), user mjjf correctly comments that the answer can be found on a [question asked on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167248/what-does-the-idiom-phrase-but-i-digress-mean).  Given how closely linked ELL and ELU are, it feels like the ELL question should be "closed as duplicate"... but there isn't a duplicate on this stack exchange, only on another related one.

Should we close the question?  If so, *how* should we close it, given that you can't select a question on another stack exchange?  If not, should we basically copy the answer over here, maybe rewriting it slightly to avoid plagiarism?  That doesn't seem right to me either.

Comment: This [has been discussed on ELU's meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11322/80039) . Do you think it would be helpful to close your question because there are answers on another site written from the perspective of a different community?

Comment: This has been a constant issue with Stack Exchange: duplicate questions posted on different Stack Exchange websites. I believe the only good solution is Stack Exchange implementing the ["crossover questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/178179) feature that has been suggested years ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Is the question ***off-topic*** on ELL?
  Vote to close it.
- Is the question a **duplicate** of an older question on ELL?
  Vote to close it as a duplicate because **the answer can be found on ELL**.
- Is the original post a duplicate of an older question but on **a different site**?
  Check to see it is not written by the same author. If it is, this is called [cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), it is generally frowned upon. Users can flag the post to draw a moderator's attention who will likely close or delete it.
  If the two posts were written by two completely different authors with a gap of one or more years; ELL users can leave it open, vote to close because it is off-topic on ELL, or flag for it to be migrated to the other site where it can be closed as a duplicate.
- Is the post **on-topic** and **has never been asked before on ELL**? I see four choices:
  a) Edit, if it improves the post
  b) Leave it alone
  c) Cast a vote
  c) Consider posting an answer.

Comment: I'm looking at a post currently flagged as a duplicate of an ELU post. Can you point me to the origins of your statements in the third point? Specifically, (1) examples of questions closed/deleted by mods because they were cross-posted, OR a policy document or Meta which sanctions this; (2) the thing about two different users at least a year apart? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I've read [this question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/should-we-close-questions-that-are-exact-duplicates-of-open-elu-questions/639#639) and while there seems to be a clear answer, it goes back to the site's infancy, so there's a reasonable chance it's not current.

Comment: @gotube https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7893/should-we-close-as-duplicate-from-a-different-site/7896#7896

Comment: @gotube I don't think it's actually possible to close a question on ELL as a duplicate of an older question but from a  different site. Mods can  migrate the "duplicate", leave it open or close it for being off-topic. Perhaps check with Laurel or Glorfindel who have been members of different communities for a substantial number of years

Comment: Thanks for that helpful link. It doesn't mention the 1-year-gap-and-two-different-users heuristic, and seems to contradict your statement that mods will probably close or delete the question. Can you show me something that supports those things? I don't have any preferences myself on how this should be handled; this is just me doing my due diligence before acting.

Comment: @gotube  Then it must have been my own, very sensible idea :). Have you asked Glorfindle and Laurel for their input? They are members and moderators of several SE websites, and also frequent contributors to SE Meta