# Cross posting between ELL and EL&U

Tags: discussion, questions, english-language-and-usage

An example is this: [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen)

There is no such question on ELL and is only on EL&U, but I am assuming it is not allowed to post this on ELL. Am I right?

Comment: Related: [Should we close a question that is a duplicate on ELU?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5599/should-we-close-a-question-that-is-a-duplicate-on-elu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-posting is [generally frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/295232), though some new users obviously don't know it and ask a question in two places, hoping to get an answer quicker. But I fail to see any benefit in re-posting a well-established EL&U question here.

Note that it's certainly possible to tailor one question to two different audiences, e.g. English linguists and English learners. Whether that's useful in this particular case, I doubt it.